# User routes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a problem with setting up user routes in a rails application.

In routes.rb I added `resources :users`.

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
     resources :users

  root :to => 'xxx#home' 
  match '/about', to: 'xxx#about'
  match '/test', to: 'xxx#test'
  match '/news', to: 'xxx#news'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'

end
```

In users_controller.rb I added:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

    def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

And I have created new show.html.rb file with lines:

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

But when I'm deploying to heroku I get this info, and I can't see that page.

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/1
```

Is there some solution for this, or I have done something wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, it should work. What does the log say ?

Comment: Heroku log said: heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/1 host=testapp.herokuapp.com fwd=78.0.234.91 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=25ms status=404 bytes=728. I get a 500 error when the page is loaded. I thought it's because there is no added user in DB but i have user with id:1.

Comment: Is that the only thing the logs show? There's usually a stack trace on the logs.

Comment: Before databse migration on heroku there is 500 error and I get: heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/1 | ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist |  LINE 4: WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass. After migration, error 404 pops up with next lines in log:  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=1):

Comment: are you sure you have a user with id=1 in the db? you said you have this problem when deploying, so you have switched from development environment to production environment, the db should be empty, save for records created via db:seed

Comment: Yeah, new user was created in rails console and I get user info output with User.find(1). Seeds.rb is empty.

Comment: No progress, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the user with `id=1` exists on heroku ? If so, did you use ?

```
$ heroku run console
```

This command brings up the rails console in production environment. In it, did you do something like that?

```
u = User.create(somehash_with_attrs)
# .. or
u = User.new
# ... 
u.save
u.id # => 1 or 23
# If your are not sure which id your user has try the following
User.first.id
```

And did you know that `yourapp.domain/users/1` points to the user record with `id=1` **and not** the first record in your database.

Comment: The solution was in: heroku run console. I could reach users in development environment but in production environment db was empty as @m_x mentioned. Just one more question, users must be added directly in production, I thought all data will be ready for use with "heroku run rake db:migrate" command from development environment?

Comment: db data is completely separated for each environment. If your app makes assumption about data in your db you might want to write a seed.rb - http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Answer (score 0):

Let's see your migration file. PG can't find a table named Users (emphasis on plural). So, after you run your migration, it looks like it finds the table.

How did you create your user in the console? If you used, say u = User.new or u = User.build, be sure you do u.save to ensure it's actually saved to the database.